# no emails for a user account

Tags: author

Is it possible to create a user account without an email. Just a username?

I saw that there is a plugin to allow multiple authors under one email. Does anyone have any recommendations on other ways to do this. I know this not ideal but I have one user who will posting on behalf of multiple users. Having the user verify their email through gravatar for each new author is a

http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/allow-multiple-accounts/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible via Add New under the Users tab, however, the [`wp_create_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) function will let you create users without an email address:

```
$username = 'someuser';
$pass = 'swordfish';
$new_user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $pass );
```

You'd have to wrap that in a basic plugin and provide some sort of UI for adding users.

Answer (score 0):

such a plugin exists:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/optional-email/
but hasn't been maintained for a while.  Still works on one of my sites however.